# Installing Rails with RVM, while checking rail -v: bundler-1.1.5 conflicts with bundler (~> 1.0.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler

I'm having a dearly hard time getting my rails environment up. Here is the issue.

```
$ gem install rails --version 3.0.1

Successfully installed rails-3.0.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.0.1...

$ rails -v

/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1637:in `raise_if_conflicts': **Unable to activate rails-3.0.1, because bundler-1.1.5 conflicts with bundler (~> 1.0.0) (Gem::LoadError)**
    from /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-    p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:746:in `activate'
    from /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1232:in `gem'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails3tutorial/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails3tutorial/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails3tutorial/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Here in lies the issue. I've reinstalled ruby. I've installed 1.8.7, 1.9.2, 1.9.3 and still no luck across the board.

i've run
   $ gem update bundler

But bundle is 'up to date', so still no luck

I've really poked at this all day now, and with no luck I open my palms to you all.

Comment: did you tell RVM which version of Ruby to use?

Comment: For example: specify your ruby version to RVM: `rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290` and install your app's bundle: `bundle install` and run the rails version command within the context of the bundle: `bundle exec -v` -- what happens when you try that?

Answer (score 1):

the issue is that in `@global` gemset you have higher version of bundler then the one required.

you can either specify the version on command line:

```
bundle _1.0.27_ exec rails -v
```

or use `Gemfile`:

```
printf 'source :rubygems\ngem "rails", "3.0.1"\n'
rails -v
```

this assumed you have the gem **rubygems-bundler** - but it comes by default with RVM so you should have it.

and last - remove bundler from `@global`:

```
rvm @global do gem uninstall bundler
```

but there is one caveat - while reinstalling ruby gem bundler will be installed again.